# How to remove extra blank lines between if statement and opening brackets

Tags: c#, rider, editorconfig

I am writing a .editorconfig for a c# project. I want blank lines between an if statement and the opening brackets to be automatically removed.

Before formatting:

```
if (1 == 0)


{
    // Do something
}
```

After formatting:

```
if (1 == 0)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Is there a property responsible for this?

Comment: The .editorconfig file describes how the code should _look_ like, it doesn't specify how that is achieved. That is the task of whatever IDE you're using.

Comment: Since I'd consider not having a blank line between the conditional statement and the body the default and I never saw it any different (until now :) ), I'd assume that this particular formatting setting is not a dedicated property.